# Detecting if a Cron job is running on a staging server

Tags: php, cron

I'm building a website that will run a series of cron tasks daily to update information in a database that is then used in the site. I have three environments setup: development (my computer), staging and live. Both staging and live are accounts on shared hosting. The problem I have is in deciding which database access credentials to use depending on which environment the code is running on. Ideally all three would have the same credentials but as both staging and live are on a shared server I can't control the name of the database. I've mirrored the live database name and access credentials on my own computer but I can't do this on staging.

What I want to do is to automatically select the correct credentials for the correct environment when my cron task runs, something like this:

```
if(environment === staging) {
  //define db access constants for staging here
 else {
  //define db access constants for live or dev here
}}
```

Normally for this sort of thing I'd use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] but as this is running in Cron the $_SERVER auto global isn't available. How could I detect on which environment a script is running in a cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an extra environment variable in the crontab file:

```
STAGING=1
```

and then check for `$_ENV['STAGING'] == 1`.

Or even

```
HOSTING_ENV=PRODUCTION
```

and then check for `$_ENV['HOSTING_ENV'] == 'PRODUCTION'`.

Comment: should be `[` and `]` not `{` and `}` when accessing an array.

Comment: Thanks, I think this has just given me the solution. I'm passing variables into the script using command line parameters which show up in $argv. I'll just pass an extra parameter in on staging and will use this to decide which credentials to use.

Comment: I should clarify that I don't have access to the crontab file as I can only access the server through a CPanel interface.

Comment: @scoates Good point. I've been perling with hashes recently, so curly braces were on my mind. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable solutions that ajreal and gms8994 are both good. Another method is to use [php_uname()](http://php.net/php_uname) to fetch the current hostname:

```
sean@gimmebarvm-sean:~$ php -r 'echo php_uname("n") . "\n";'
gimmebarvm-sean
```

Answer (score 1):

run your cron via WGET by calling it by a domain rather by PHP command line

you will then be able to detect the platform by its domain